# Table initialization in Zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

i am new to the Zend Framework 2.Any body can tell me that where i can initialize the tb table in ZF2 model? For example i want to select all the records form the user table in FZ2 model.

Regards,
Tauqeer

Answer (score 0):

```
     $db = $this->db;
     $select = $this->db->select(false)
               ->from('user');
```

Try this one

refer this url http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html

Comment: The documentation you linked is for ZF 1.12.

Comment: select a version option is there, anyway " http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html " this is the link for version 2. But that coding works fine for me